# Count occurrences of a char in a string (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file in windows to parse all the file names available in a folder and move the files that match some conditions to a folder.
I have already create the loop cycle with FOR command and I have set the file name to a variable.
Now I need to check how many "-" hypen characters are in the variable of the file name; if the occurrences of this character are more than 10 the file should not be moved. Additionally I need to check also if a space is inside the file name: also in this case the file cannot be moved.
Please: in which way can I create the script to check the number of occurrences of the hypen in the variable and the presence of the space character ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This code just uses the `for /f` tokenizer to determine if the file should be copied or excluded. In the case of the hypen, 10 `-` characters generate 11 tokens, more or less is a cause of exclusion. In the case of the space, a single space generates two tokens. This is the simple part, but

- As a run of hypen could be present, and the `for /f` tokenizer handles consecutive delimiters as only one delimiter, each hypen is replaced with `-#` and the file name prefixed with `#` to ensure a correct split.
- To do a string replacement we need a normal variable, not the `for` replaceable parameter. So, we need delayed expansion to be able to read the content of the changed variable. But, with delayed expansion active the `!` characters becomes a problem as the parser will try to interpret it as a variable reference. To avoid it, delayed expansion is enabled only when needed and disabled again.
- To handle the space splitting, the filename is prefixed and suffixed with `#` to ensure that initial or ending spaces are properly handled.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Generate a set of test files
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5-6 -7-8-9-10.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9.testFile"
    type nul > "-----------.testFile"
    type nul > "----------.testFile"
    type nul > "!-----------!.testFile"
    type nul > "!----------!.testFile"
    type nul > "noSpaces.testFile"
    type nul > "this file has spaces.testFile"

    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5!!-6-!!7-8-9-10-11-12.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3-4-5!!-6-!!7-8-9-10-11.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3!!-4-5-6-7-8-9!!-10.testFile"
    type nul > "0-1-2-3!!-4-5-6-7-8!-!9.testFile"
    type nul > "no!Sp!aces.testFile"
    type nul > "this !file! has spaces.testFile"


    for %%f in (*) do (
        rem The default behaviour is not to exclude the file
        set "exclude="

        rem Test the hypen conditions
        set "fileName=%%~nf"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "tokens=1,11,12 delims=-" %%a in ("#!fileName:-=-#!") do (
            endlocal 
            rem Testing less than 10 hypen
            if "%%~b"=="" set "exclude=1"
            rem Testing more than 10 hypen
            if not "%%~c"=="" set "exclude=1"
        )

        rem Test if the file name contains a space
        for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("#%%~nf#") do if not "%%~b"=="" set "exclude=1" 

        rem Now we know what to do with the file
        if defined exclude (
            echo EXCLUDE "%%~ff"
        ) else (
            echo COPY "%%~ff"
        )
    )

    del /q "*.testFile"
```

Another way of doing it is to filter the list of files to only retrieve those that should be processed

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /b 
    ^| findstr /v /c:" " 
    ^| findstr /r /x /c:"[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*"
') do echo COPY %%~fa
```

Comment: First of all thank you. I have not explained well my need.  I need to exclude the filenames that don't have 10 hyphens (therefore the filename must  have 10 hypens and not more or less) and two consecutive hyphens should be counted as 2 hyphens. The presence of a space or more spaces should be considered as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for determining the number of hyphens contained within a string would be to compare the length of the original string with the length of the string with the hyphens removed: the number of hyphens is the difference in length.

```
1. Save the length of the original string
2. Remove all hyphens from the string
3. Compare the length of the new string to that of the original:
        originalLength - newLength = numberOfHyphens
```

Similarly, this method can be used to determine if a space exists. If the length of the original string is greater than the length of the string minus spaces, then a space must have been removed and thus must have existed in the original string.

Comment: Hello your approach is good but unfortunately I don't know how to check the lenght of a string and remove the hyphens from the string. Thx.

Comment: Hi, would whoever downvoted please explain why? If my approach is wrong or unhelpful I would like to know how to make it better.

Comment: @DesAdams I agree your technique should work. I suspect that it was downvoted because you didn't provide an example.

Comment: @bantonacci I consider those things to be outside the scope of this question. I agree, I could provide an example as Tony mentioned, but I had intended merely to provide an algorithm, or at the very least guidance, and not an answer that could be copied without needing to understand how it worked. I gave such an answer expecing that the exact syntax for doing such things in your language (Windows batch) could be researched elsewhere if necessary. After all, there are bound to be much better resources for those sorts of topics than what I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you, you don't really want to know *how many hypens* a name have, but just to know if the name *have more than 10 hypens*. This can be easily achieved via the `"tokens=12 delims=-"` option of `for /F` command:

**EDIT**: Code modified accordingly to a *new request* stated in a comment. The new code check if a name *contain exactly 10 hypens* and don't include space.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%a in (one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-end.txt
            one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-ten-end.txt
            one-two-three-four-five-six--eight-nine-ten-end.txt
            one-two-three-four-five---eight-nine-ten-end.txt
            one-two-three-four-five----nine-ten-end.txt
            one-two-three-four-five-----ten-end.txt
            one----------end.txt
            ----------.txt
            one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-ten-eleven-end.txt
            "one-two-three-four-five-SIX SEVEN--eight-nine-ten-end.txt") do (
   set "fileName=%%~a"
   call :checkName
)
goto :EOF


:checkName
echo Checking "%fileName%"
set "result=Don't have 10 hypens"
for /F "tokens=11,12 delims=-" %%a in ("%filename:--=X-X-X%") do (
   if "%%a" neq "" if "%%b" equ "" set "result=Name correct"
)
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ("%fileName%") do if "%%a" neq "" set "result=Include space"
echo %result%
exit /B
```

Comment: This approach will fail if some of the hypen characters are consecutive.

Comment: First of all thank you. I have not explained well my need.  I need to exclude the filenames that don't have 10 hyphens (therefore the filename must  have 10 hypens and not more or less) and two consecutive hyphens should be counted as 2 hyphens. The presence of a space or more spaces should be considered as well. Thanks !

Comment: See the edit in my answer. You should not state new specifications in comments, but modify the original question instead and just leave a comment as an advice that _the specifications had changed_.

Comment: Did you saw my answer? Solve it your problem?